# Issue: Violation of Permissions policy remove app by google

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm trying to release an app on google play console. There one declaration form which is required 19 option core functionality. But the problem is that I have to remove previous all permission.

When app review rejects my app send me auto-generated mail.

After reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions for the following reason(s):
Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler). Please remove these permissions from your app.
Default handler capability was listed on your declaration form, but your app does not appear to have default handler capability. Please submit a revised declaration form.

What I'm missing?

Please help me out.

Comment: Check [this](https://gist.github.com/manishpatelgt/224a330a5d4c7eaf783ca3ff5d522274)

Answer (score 0):

1. Fill-up google docs for permission.
2. Make sure your permission is given in manifest and give the pop up in user level.
3. Contact google developers for Details.

[See this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)

Comment: Same issue i have facing. My point i have removed all those permission and resubmit the app. Still play console asking to fill the Permissions Declaration Form.
But i haven't use that permission. Why i want to fill

Comment: Update your question with your gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Google has blocked some permissions like READ_CALL_LOG, WRITE_CALL_LOG and SMS related permissions. Basically they are saying that if you are trying to send SMS or handle Calls like TrueCaller, submit your application we will take a look at it.

I think they are aiming for quality application that are developed by viable developer companies or individuals. Also, SMS phishing and similar harmful applications are automatically ereased from Play Store.

Also if you have a beta or alpha with permissions you need to remove them too. To be sure remove the apks with harmful permissions from artifact library to be sure.